# Scroll down specific area by Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How to scroll down specific area of webpage.
Because i need to scroll down on linkedin message section.
NOT scroll down entire screen. Scroll down on specific area.
Please help me.

[Please check image. CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knP0i.png)

Comment: Hi @ganbaa and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, add your code attempts so far, along with a minimal reproducible example. Also, I suggest that you have a read on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as it will help you attracting good answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

1. [selenium `driver.execute_script()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/execute_script-driver-method-selenium-python/) for running js script
2. [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) or jQuery method `scroll`
3. [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for finding your element in the list

Comment: i want to use Selenium python. Please check that picture. I cant upload my whole code. Because its very long and complicated. It will waste your time. So please help me for support fresh code for that area.